# Modifying Task 'Name' field with Apex/Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

So, I would like to access and modify the 'Name' field seen on this page.

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=task_fields.htm&language=en_US

```
    Task t = new Task();
    t.Name = 'test name';
```

That will give me an error saying 'Invalid field Name for SObject Task'

I think this is a flaw in my basic understanding between the point-and-click interface and the Apex code.

Answer (score 0):

The help you've linked to is <strike>idiot</strike> end-user friendly. It lists field labels (that can be translated for example).

When you refer to fields in code you use the API names (which change very rarely, like column names in a database table). You probably encountered custom fields that have API names ending with `__c`?

Here's the "pro" version of the help file for Tasks: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

I think the field you want to modify is `WhoId`. You'll need to put there a Contact/Lead's `Id` and then when viewed in the browser it'll show a link with the target's `Name` (like any other lookup).